# How can I install a service under a different account than the LocalSystem account using Win32 API?

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, windows-services

How can I install a service under a different account than the LocalSystem account using Win32 API?

I am using the following code to install the service. I want to install this service under a different account. The last two parameters take username and password but when I give so it throws an error. Is there any specific way of giving username and password here?

```
IntPtr sv_handle = CreateService(sc_handle, svcName, svcDispName,
                     SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS, SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS,
                     SERVICE_AUTO_START, SERVICE_ERROR_NORMAL,
                     svcPath, null, 0, null, null, null);
```

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: "The user account name specified in the lpServiceStartName parameter does not exist."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What format are you using for `lpServiceStartName`?

It needs to be  `machinename\\username` (or `.\\username`) if the user name is local or part of a workgroup otherwise it should be `domainname\\username`.

Comment: perfect answer what i wanted (domain\\username)...i tried using domain\username and it gave error 22. thanks a lot. a single '\' can make much difference